# Unmet depedencies and not enough free space (eventhough i have plenty)

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, disk-usage

I'm super new in this Ubuntu world, so i have been having a hard time looking for solutions( also English isnt my first language so please be kind).
I recently tried installing TeXLive but the instllation stopped due to not having enough free space, even though I gave 49GB to my Ubuntu partition and Disk Manager points ive only used 0.3%. Moreover, every time i try uninstalling the TeXLive package I end up having tons of errors with unmet dependencies, and ive tried `apt --fix-broken install`as suggested in the Terminal i get:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I've tried everything I've found on the internet and nothing seems to work, so any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: We can offer better advice if you provide complete input and output instead of summarizing. Summaries tend to omit the details we need to help you best.

Comment: Did you run sudo apt update before anything else to update your package list?  Your used space of 0.3%  makes no sense, typical install would be around 20% of your 49GB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the same command with as root? You can do it adding `sudo` (Runs the command as super user / root) before the command.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

The "Permission Denied" means that your user is not able to modify some files needed for the command to run (that is normal), only the root user can do it. Apt gave you a hint: `are you root?`